# TextView not visible in Release (ProGuard)

Tags: android, textview, proguard, android-databinding

**Project:**
https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample

When I run the app in the `Development_Debug` Build Flavor, the `TextView`
[`cat_title`](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_movie_detail_app_bar_layout.xml#L68)
is visible, and works as expected, i.e. resizing as the `AppBarLayout` is scrolled collapsed/expanded.

However, when I run the app with the exact same code in the `Development_Release` Build Flavor with [`minifyEnabled true`](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L51-L51),
the `TextView` is just not visible anymore!

Please help. Am I missing any ProGuard rules for the library project
[CollapsingAvatarToolbar](https://github.com/datalink747/CollapsingAvatarToolbar)
that I've used to display the TextView in?

P.S.: I've used
[`DataBinding`](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L32-L32)
to load text into the `TextView`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Finally figured it out. Proguard was removing one of the fields in one of my data classes, so I made sure to keep the whole class in my ProGuard rules.